# OpenCV compare images

Tags: image, opencv, javacv

I need help with OpenCV to solve the following problem:

1. I have some pictures of one place
2. Each photo compare with the first
3. in the photos except the first I need to draw the frames where there was a change

Can anyone advise me or recommend a prime example?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a job for *background substraction*.

[BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#BackgroundSubtractorMOG2%20%3a%20public%20BackgroundSubtractor) is the class you will probably want.

I have not used it myself, but here is a [tutorial](http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189)